# How to import blog posts from POP/IMAP?

Tags: 8, importing-exporting

Is it possible to import blog posts from POP/IMAP?

I found two modules [Mailhandler](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailhandler) and [Inmail](https://www.drupal.org/project/inmail), but can not make them work together. Both are in dev-state and Mailhandler and it seems that no new commits were added for some time (since summer 2016).

Maybe there are other modules for implementing this functionality?

Comment: Asking for module recommendations is considered off topic here. Try reaching out to the maintainer of the projects to see if they have thoughts on your idea; perhaps you can assist in pushing development further along.